# ¿ Cómo hacer método onClick con <arraylist>?

Tags: java, android

Tengo en mi aplicación un drawer (con dierentes Fragment) y en una de ellas me salen dos pestañas con diferentes opciones a elegir de comida y quiero activar el método onClick para que al clickar en una de esas opciones me lleve a una activity pero no sé como... tengo lo siguiente que es donde tengo declarado todo lo que me saldrá, pero cómo lo hago?

```
public class Comida {
private float precio;
private String nombre;
private int idDrawable;

public Comida(float precio, String nombre, int idDrawable) {
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.idDrawable = idDrawable;


}

public static final List<Comida> ASIGNATURAS = new ArrayList<Comida>();
public static final List<Comida> BEBIDAS = new ArrayList<>();
public static final List<Comida> POSTRES = new ArrayList<>();
public static final List<Comida> PLATILLOS = new ArrayList<>();

static {
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(5, "Matematicas III", R.drawable.camarones));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(3.2f, "Rosca Herbárea", R.drawable.rosca));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(12f, "Sushi Extremo", R.drawable.sushi));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(9, "Sandwich Deli", R.drawable.sandwich));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(34f, "Lomo De Cerdo Austral", R.drawable.lomo_cerdo));



    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(5, "Matematicas III", R.drawable.camarones));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(3.2f, "Rosca Herbárea", R.drawable.rosca));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(12f, "Sushi Extremo", R.drawable.sushi));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(9, "Sandwich Deli", R.drawable.sandwich));
    ASIGNATURAS.add(new Comida(34f, "Lomo De Cerdo Austral", R.drawable.lomo_cerdo));

    BEBIDAS.add(new Comida(3, "FÍSICA I", R.drawable.cafe));
    BEBIDAS.add(new Comida(12, "Coctel Tronchatoro", R.drawable.coctel));
    BEBIDAS.add(new Comida(5, "Jugo Natural", R.drawable.jugo_natural));
    BEBIDAS.add(new Comida(24, "Coctel Jordano", R.drawable.coctel_jordano));
    BEBIDAS.add(new Comida(30, "Botella Vino Tinto Darius", R.drawable.vino_tinto));

    POSTRES.add(new Comida(2, "Postre De Vainilla", R.drawable.postre_vainilla));
    POSTRES.add(new Comida(3, "Flan Celestial", R.drawable.flan_celestial));
    POSTRES.add(new Comida(2.5f, "Cupcake Festival", R.drawable.cupcakes_festival));
    POSTRES.add(new Comida(4, "Pastel De Fresa", R.drawable.pastel_fresa));
    POSTRES.add(new Comida(5, "Muffin Amoroso", R.drawable.muffin_amoroso));
}



public float getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public int getIdDrawable() {
    return idDrawable;
}
}
```

Por cierto, mi aplicación funciona con fragments, no puede una activity saltar y machacar toda la pantalla de mi app, debe respetar el drawer.

Mi main activity:

```
package com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import com.herprogramacion.restaurantericoparico.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_principal);




        agregarToolbar();

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        if (navigationView != null) {
            prepararDrawer(navigationView);
            // Seleccionar item por defecto
            seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        }
    }

    private void agregarToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            // Poner ícono del drawer toggle
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }

    private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
        Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.CALENDARIO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoPerfil();
                break;
            case R.id.PRIMERO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentPrimero();
                break;
            case R.id.SEGUNDO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentSegundo();
                break;
            case R.id.TERCERO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentTercero();
                break;
            case R.id.CUARTO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentCuarto();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "AndroidSolved");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "si que funciona");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                break;

        }
        if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                    .commit();
        }

        // Setear título actual
        setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: "no puede una activity saltar y machacar toda la pantalla de mi app, debe respetar el drawer." te refieres a que la Activity no debe de abrirse sobre tu Activity que contiene el Fragment?

Comment: Exacto Elena, es eso, no puede abrirse encima de lo que tengo hecho.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías definir en que elemento vas a mostrar tus `ArrayList`, por ejemplo si los vas a mostrar en un `ListView` por medio del método `setOnItemClickListener()` puedes obtener la posición de tu elemento en el `ArrayList`(variable position) y mediante un `intent` abrir otra `Activity`.

Por ejemplo suponiendo que tu objeto `Comida()` tiene un método `getNombre(`) para obtener el nombre, obtendríamos el nombre del elemento seleccionado de esta forma y además crearías un intent para abrir otra Activity:

```
    mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   //Puedes obtener el elemento dentro de tu ArrayList mediante get() y la posición.
                  String nombre = ASIGNATURAS.get(position).getNombre();
                  //Abre otra activity.
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtraActivity.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Elena, esto debo ponerlo exactamente dónde? ¿ Dentro de                                                      " public Comida (float precio, String nombre, int idDrawable) {
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.idDrawable = idDrawable;


} " ??

Comment: ¿ Podemos hablar en chat ?

Comment: O hay que ponerlo en el Main activity? Me da error si lo pongo en el .java de arriba.

Comment: Esta es la que te decía Elena... esto dónde debo ponerlo exactamente? En el MainActivity o en el mismo fragment? ( mi app es un navigation drawer con diferentes fragment)

Comment: Me refiero... como sé la posición de un elemento en una lista? Podemos hablar esto por privado? Solo me falta esto de "lo mas gordo de la app" y me lleva loco... espero respuesta. gracias.

Comment: hola!, para saber la posición del elemento en la lista se recibe como el parametro position, el primer elemento es 0 el segundo 1, así sucecivamente!

Comment: si agrega un link de chat para hablar!

Comment: ¿ cómo se hace? ya creamos uno pero no lo encuentro! :S

Comment: créala tú esta vez por favor ;)